# Плагин-калькулятор расчёта услуг wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

извините, немного туплю. Не могу подобрать плагин под калькулятор на WordPress. Нужен [как здесь](https://www.agentq.ru/service) (https://www.agentq.ru/service)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кто-нибудь делал подобное и подскажет, на чем можно попробовать.
Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение: плагин ez Form Calculator.
Очень гибкий, смог сделать похожий калькулятор под себя.
Надеюсь, что кому-нибудь помог этим ответом.